# Show linear independence of "functions"

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of functions, all members of a vector space, how would one show that they are "linearly" independent?

I know that one needs to show that a linear combination equals 0 if and only if all coefficients are zero, but how is that done when the linear combination is something like; $$c_1 + c_2x + c_3x^2 = 0$$
My first thought was to set $x = 0$, and then conclude that $c_1 = 0$, but what then?

Or, seeing that it's a polynomial, is it possible to say that we consider the zero on the right side to be a polynomial of 3rd degree but with all coefficients being zero, and thus those two are equal  only if all coefficients are zero?

Comment: Why the quotation marks?

Comment: are you assuming that the *target space* of those functions is also a vector space?

Comment: The $0$ on the right is the zero *function*.

Answer (score 1):

Like someone pointed out in the comments, the $0$ on the right is the $0$ *function* , meaning a function in which every point of its domain maps to zero. Now, you have a polynomial of degree 2. How many zeros can a polynomial of degree 2 have?